# JMeter - 407 Response message:Proxy Authentication Required while playback blazemeter recording

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I have jmeter version 5.2.1. I have recorded a blaze meter script. I opened jmeter from command prompt using the below syntax (jmeter -H proxy -P 80 -u username -a password)

Then on the GUI, I have given the proxy details in HTTPRequestDefault, also at the test level as shown in the screenshot.

But still I keep getting Response code:407
Response message:Proxy Authentication Required

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your authentication data might just be wrong? Unfortunately, the 407 status doesn't really distinguish between "no credentials" and "wrong credentials".

Comment: It is my domain credentials, using which I can access internet. SO the credentials are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the issue. I had to change the implementation dropdown to Java

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **domain** credentials you need to supply another property to let JMeter know about your network domain, in particular [http.proxyDomain](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#proxy_config)

So you need to launch JMeter as:

```
jmeter -Jhttp.proxyDomain=YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE
```

in order to make change permanent - add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
http.proxyDomain=YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE
```

More information:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the reply. I tried pint 1 and 2 as per your suggestion. But it did not solve the issue